# Touchpad is not showing up in the dconf Editor?

Tags: touchpad, scrolling, dconf

I am running Ubuntu gnome 16.04 and wanted to create key bindings to change programs with horizontal scroll, like MacOS.

But when I go into dconf Editor:
org > gnome > settings-daemon > peripherals >

the touchpad doesn't show up.
I am running an hp laptop with synaptics drivers.

Answer (score 0):

With Synaptics, use xclient in terminal to adjust. No reasonable gui exists to match that. Run 'xclient -l' to see current. Then new values are tested from cli with key=value pairs. When you find what you like, then you put in a config file.

I am not running Synaptics anymore, but I there is a template config under /usr/share/synaptics/X11 (or similar). You copy that to /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d. Then put in your settings.

If you have trouble finding that config file, get a file list from the Synaptics package (dpkg -l synaptics). If you get stuck, while back here and I will get a link for you.